# Яндекс Геокодер. полигон

Tags: яндекс-карты, геокодирование, геокодинг

Есть ли возможность с помощью Яндекс.Геокодера или иных сервисов получаеть не кокретные координаты цента объекта , а его полигоны. (облась нахождения объекта, к примеру улицы)

Answer (score 1):

В ответе Геокодера есть поле [boundedBy](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/reference/response_structure-docpage/#response_structure__response), это минимальные границы области (в большинстве случаев это прямоугольник), в которые можно вписать искомый объект.

Полигоны же самого объекта получить в API и, в частности, в геокодере нельзя.